# Drupal 8 - How to move comments into a separate tab?

Tags: drupal, tabs, comments, drupal-8

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: Discussion tab with all the comments]

All the comments for each node are shown only on a separate tab "Discussions". Any idea about the most proper way to implement this?

What I have found so far is that I can achieve nearly all of this by installing the [View Mode Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_mode_page) module, but it does not give me a separate tab. Any way to do that?

I'd appreciate any help or direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I have found an answer to this:

- Views to add a new path like `/node/%node/discussions`
- Menu Tab with "Discussions" name
- Contextual filter to show only the node from the argument
- Display content with a specified view mode (in my case it was a new view mode with only comments displayed)
- Save
- Clear Cache (otherwise you won't see a tab)

Subsequently I had to install Redirect and Subpathauto modules in order to make the tab to comply with the node URL alias.